# Tranformation of $X \sim Unif(0, 1)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable with a uniform distribution $a=0$ and $b=1$. And $Y=-\frac{1}{λ}ln(x), \; λ>0$.

Find the density function of $Y$.

Comment: @Eric That's irrelevant since equality is considered a.s. only.

Comment: @A.S. : Irrelevant in measure, not irrelevant to the domain of the function.  And if we change the domain -- new function.

Comment: @Eric Who cares about the underlying space (which is $\Omega$ and not $[0,1]$ vs $(0,1)$), especially when the question is about pdf only? I fail to see how exact range of $X$ matters (you could take out a countable number of points from the range of $X$ (reassign them to keep $\Omega$ the same) and $Y$ will stay the same a.s.).

Comment: @A.S. : Since "no one cares", I choose to require that $Y$ is a random variable on $(0,1)$.  Now $Y$ does not exist.  Alternatively, I choose the measure space $[0,1)$, which intersects the domain of $Y$ in exactly one point.  So apparently we do care.  Did you mean that the domain of $Y$ is the measure space $(-\infty, 0]$ or $(-\infty, 0)$?  Because the measurable functions on one are not the measurable functions on the other.

Comment: @Eric Who cares about (common) domain of $X$ and $Y$? Are you confusing domain with range? $X:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ with $U(0,1)$ distribution, hence $Y:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ has $\exp(\lambda)$ distribution. You don't get to make any choices regarding $Y$, as $Y=-\lambda^{-1}\log X$ is set/given.

Comment: @A.S. : You do realize there was no minus sign in the version of this question I commented on?  And you seem to think that functions exist independently of their domains.  It is not enough to tell me the expression used to convert input to $Y$ into output of $Y$, you must also tell me its domain.  And the domain of $Y$ is not the domain of $X$, although you seem to think that it is.

Comment: @Eric The minus sign is an irrelevant feature. Of course $Y(\omega)=f(X(\omega))$ and $X(\omega)$ have the same domain - how can it be otherwise? In this case, as is customarily, the underlying domains is completely irrelevant - only distributions matter. The problem didn't state $Y\sim f(X)$ (the you have a choice of domain for $Y$) but even the zero measure variations in $X$ had no effect on distribution of $Y$.

Comment: @A.S. : I do see that many people have edited the question.  I see no verification from the OP that they have not changed the intent.  An r.v. is a measurable function, therefore has a domain.  The domain of X in all  versions of the question is some interval from $0$ to $1$.  The function $y = \frac{-1}{\lambda} \ln x$ takes values in the interval from $0$ to $\infty$, so the random variable $Y$ is a measurable function on the interval $0$ to $\infty$, which is not the domain of $X$.  I'd use interval notation, but the OP's problem doesn't clarify whether $0$ is in the domain of $X$.

Comment: @Eric You are confusing range and domain. The domain of $X$ doesn't have to be $[0,1]$ or it's variants - it can be be any rich enough $\Omega$. The range of $X$ doesn't have to be $[0,1]$ either - $X$ can take values outside of $[0,1]$ as long as probability of that is $0$ and similarly it can skip value inside $[0,1]$ as long as that set has (Lebesgue) measure zero. $Y=f(X)$ has the same domain as $X$, $\mu((0,\infty)\setminus range(Y))=0$, $\mu_Y(range(Y)\setminus (0,\infty))=0$ and $Y\sim \exp(\lambda)$. You seem confused re domain vs range and general nature of random variables.

Comment: @A.S. : And you seem confused about the basic properties of functions.  If you do not specify a domain, you have not specified a function.  A r.v. is a measurable function.  No domain -- no measurable function.  Handwaving that surely there is some set on which this works fails to meet the definitions of the objects involved.

Comment: @Eric I'm not the one confusing domain with range. It's completely immaterial what the domain of $X$ (and consequently of $Y$) is as long it is rich enough to support $\mu_X$. It could be any $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ with boundaries in extended reals. From probabilistic point of view, the source space is simply a useful hidden underlying feature - little more than that. That's why specifying distribution of a random variable is enough to specify the variable without ever announcing the underlying $\Omega$ (as long as such exists - I think there are some multi-dimensional pathologies).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a try. For $y > 0,$ the cumulative distribution function of $Y$ is
$$
F(y) = P(Y\leq y) = P\left(-\frac{1}{\lambda} ln(X) \leq y\right) = P\left(X \geq e^{-\lambda y}\right)\\ = 1-P\left(X \leq e^{-\lambda y}\right) =1- e^{-\lambda y}.
$$
Then the pdf of $Y$ function would be the derivative of $F(y)$, i.e.
$$
f(y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y},
$$
for $y > 0.$

Comment: I have edited your Answer to include the applicable range of $y$ (avoiding negative values) and to use $X$ for the uniform random variable. (+1). Revise if you object.

Answer (score 0):

This problem illustrates how a random variable $U \sim Unif(0,1)$ can be used to obtain an $exponential$ random variable $X \sim Exp(rate = \lambda).$ (See your text or Wikipedia on 'exponential distribution'.) The main purpose of this Answer is to illustrate
the result you can find using CDFs as in the Answer by @Mike (or using other methods, if you prefer).

This relationship is often used in simulation studies because the 'pseudorandom generator' in most software packages produces observations
that act like a random sample from $Unif(0,1).$ (Following the
Comment by @EricTowers, $0$ values are not generated in practice,
and have 'probability 0' in theory.)

Below is a short simulation in R, based on a sample of size $n = 30,000$. The histogram on the left shows the results from the random number generator and the one on the right shows the exponentially distributed values along with the density function of $Exp(\lambda = 10).$

```
 u = runif(30000, 0, 1);  x = -(1/10)*log(u)  # 'runif' renerates random obs
 mean(u);  var(u)
 ## 0.4985593    # approx E(U) = 1/2
 ## 0.08300676   # approx V(U) = 1/12
 mean(x);  var(x);  sd(x)
 ## 0.1000483    # approx E(X) = 1/10 = 1/lambda
 ## 0.009826598
 ## 0.0991292    # approx SD(X) = 1/10

 par(mfrow=c(1,2))  # 2 panels per figure
   hist(u, prob=T, col="wheat")  # 'prob' parameter for density scale
     curve(dunif(x, 0, 1), col="blue", n=1001, add=T)     #'dunif' is PDF of UNIF
   hist(x, prob=T, ylim=c(0,10), col="skyblue2")
     curve(dexp(x, 10), lwd=2, n=1001, col="blue", add=T) #'dexp' is PDF of EXP
 par(mfrow=c(1,1))  # back to default 1-panel figures
```

[image]